# Positive elements with norm 1 in unital C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Question:

> Suppose $A$ is a unital C*-algebra, and $a,b\in A_+$ be positive such that $\|a\|=\|b\|=1$. Show $\|a-b\|=1$ *iff* there is a pure state $\omega$ such that $\omega(a)\omega(b)=0$ and $\omega(a)+\omega(b)=1$.

It's been a few months since I started self-learning C*-algebras. But sometimes I still can't see how to go about a random question like this. The main result I know regarding pure states and the norm of positive elements is Thm 5.1.11 in Murphy(1990). But not sure how to use it here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assume that there exists a pure state $\omega$ such that $\omega(a)\omega(b)=0$ and $\omega(a+b)=1$. Then
$$
\omega(a+b)^2-\omega(a-b)^2=4\omega(a)\omega(b)=0.
$$
Thus $\omega(a-b)=\omega(a+b)=1$. It follows that $\lVert a-b\rVert\geq 1$. On the other hand, $-1\leq a-b\leq 1$ implies $\lVert a-b\rVert\leq 1$.

Now assume that $\lVert a-b\rVert=1$. Since $a-b$ is self-adjoint, there exists (see below) a pure state $\omega$ on $A$ such that $\omega(a-b)^2=1$. Since $0\leq \omega(a),\omega(b)\leq 1$, we have $\omega(a)-1\leq \omega(a-b)\leq 1-\omega(b)$, hence $\omega(a-b)^2\leq \max\{1-\omega(a),1-\omega(b)\}$. Therefore $(\omega(a)-\omega(b))^2=1$ is only possible if $\omega(a)=0$ or $\omega(b)=0$.

The existence of the pure state $\omega$ is justified as follows. By Gelfand-Naimark, the unital $C^\ast$-algebra $B$ generated by $a-b$ is $\ast$-isomorphic to $C(X)$ for some compact space $X$ and $a-b$ is sent to some real-valued function $f\in C(X)$. Since $X$ is compact, there exists $x\in X$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert=\lVert f\rVert_\infty$. The measure $\delta_x$ is a pure state on $C(X)$, which gives rise to a pure state $\omega_0$ on $B$ such that $\lvert\omega_0(a-b)\rvert=\lVert a-b\rVert$. Moreover, $\omega_0$ can be extended to a pure state $\omega$ on $A$ (see Murphy, Theorem 5.1.13 for example).

Comment: Thanks. So Murphy's Thm 5.1.11 remains true for self-adjoint elements!

Comment: Just to be sure. When you say "the measure $\delta_x$ is a pure state on $C(X)$, which gives rise to a pure state $\omega_0$ on $B$ such that $|\omega_0 (a−b)|=\|a−b\|$", you mean for every pure state $\varphi$ on $C(X)$, there is a corresponding measure $\delta_x$, by the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani theorem. Right? If so, shouldn't it be $\delta_\varphi$? Why is $x$ the subscript?

Comment: No, you start with the measure $\delta_x$ (the Dirac measure at $x$), where $x$ is the point at which $f$ attains its norm. And then you transplant it back to $B$ via the Gelfand transform.

Comment: Apology for my slowness. Are you saying, on $C(X)$, map $f\mapsto f(x)$ is a pure state, because $f(x)=\int_X f(t) \delta_x(dt)$, and the Diract measure $\delta_x$ is an extreme point of all the probability measures?

Comment: There's actually no need to appeal to the Riesz (-Markov-whoever) representation theorem in this case. The point evaluation is a pure state, which can be shon in many ways, and $\delta_x$ is just a convenient notation for it.